# Uniform convergence of composition of continuous functions

Tags: real-analysis, polynomials, uniform-convergence

Let $ f,g : [0,1] -> \mathbb{R}$ are continuous one-one function such that $Range (f)\supseteq Range (g)$. Then

(a) There exist a sequence of polynomials $P_n$ such that $f(P_n)$, converges
uniformly to $g$ on $[0,1]$.

(b) There exist a sequence of polynomials $P_n$ such that $g(P_n)$ converges uniformly to $ƒ$ on $[0,1]$

(c.) There does not exist sequence of polynomials $P_n$ such that $f(P_n)$ converges uniformly to $g$ on [0,1]

(d) There does not exist sequence of polynomials $P_n$ such that $g(P_n)$ converges uniformly to $ƒ$ on $[0,1]$

I tried using Weirstrass approximation theorem which states " There exists a sequence of polynomials converging to a continuous functions $ f: [a,b]-> \mathbb{R} $ "

So $P_n$ converges uniformly to both f and g. But I don't have any idea about uniform  convergence after composition of functions.I need help with all options

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, note that there is no guarantee that we can find a sequence such that $g(P_n) \rightarrow f$: for example, take $f(x)=x$ and $g(x)=0$.

Now, to show that the other statement holds, we want to find a continuous function $h \colon [0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $f \circ h = g$, after which we may apply the Weierstrass approximation theorem. Since $f$ is a homeomorphism onto its image (this is because $[0,1]$ is compact and $\mathbb{R}$ is Hausdorff), there is a well-defined continuous function $f^{-1} \colon Range(f) \rightarrow [0,1]$ such that $f \circ f^{-1} = id_{Range(f)}$.

Now, since $Range(f) \supseteq Range(g)$, the composition $h= f^{-1} \circ g$ makes sense and is the composition of continuous functions, hence continuous. Furthermore, $f \circ h = f \circ f^{-1} \circ g = g$.

Comment: $f$ and $g$ are injective, so $g(x)=0$ is not a counterexample. [having said that, there are many counterexamples to b), just take a strictly larger range for $f$]

Comment: Of course, thanks. $f(x)=2x$ and $g(x)=\sin x$ would work (since $\sin$ is injective on $[0,1]$.